# crawling a site using php

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm working on crawling specific urls. I have 17 urls in a table an should scan the addresses and find the specific links and then read their content for some piece of information.
this part of my code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts") or die(mysql_error());
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
@$new_doc = new DOMDocument();
@$new_doc->loadHTMLFile($rec['url']);
foreach($new_doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) 
{
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if(preg_match($url_pat,$href))
    {
        preg_match_all($house_code_pat,$href,$out);
        $house_code=trim($out[0][0],'-');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mashhad` (`house_code`) VALUES ('".$house_code."')") or die();
        $error_no=mysql_errno();

        if($error_no==0)
        {
            echo $i++."<br>";

            @$doc = new DOMDocument();
            $url=$href;
            @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
        }

    }
}
}
```

I know the counter should continue to about 300 bout in this way it only continue for about 29 or 30 or 31.
when i remove the second load html and do it in this form :

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts") or die(mysql_error());
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
@$new_doc = new DOMDocument();
@$new_doc->loadHTMLFile($rec['url']);
foreach($new_doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) 
{
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if(preg_match($url_pat,$href))
    {
        preg_match_all($house_code_pat,$href,$out);
        $house_code=trim($out[0][0],'-');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mashhad` (`house_code`) VALUES ('".$house_code."')") or die();
        $error_no=mysql_errno();

        if($error_no==0)
        {
            echo $i++."<br>";

            @$doc = new DOMDocument();
            // some piece removed

        }

    }
}
}
```

it does OK just what I want. 
now what is wrong with first code?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: It may be timing out - Parsing that many URLs and retrieving the HTML for each could take a while. What is your timeout setting set to?

Comment: I didn't set, it is default.

Comment: Thanks @BrendanBullen it seems its working when i used set_time_limit(0);